# How can redirect the result of a search in another page using django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-filter

the aim of the app is to simulate somethis like this http://www.makemytrip.com/bus-tickets/

user can search available bus . When they click on search bus it redirect them to a page showing all the available bus for a specific trip

I used django filter successfully. Now the challenge is that the results needs to be seen in the results page not the search page .

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes you redirect with http://domain.com/site/page?param=1&param2 or post parameters its depends of site of search.